# set transaction read only option generates error

Tags: sql-server

Since I am new to SQL Server, this question might sound very naive to most of you. While referring a book on SQL, I came across this statement.

```
**set transaction
read only,
isolation level read uncommitted,
diagnostics size 5 ;**
```

But when executed, it gives following error.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'read'.**

Comment: This is no `read only` option. The only `SET` statement that involves [`transaction`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) just affects the isolation level. Did you read this example on-line? If so, where?

Comment: @damien_The_Unbeliever.In a book named "SQL A Beginner's Guide" by Andy Oppel & Robert Sheldon

Comment: That book is generic SQL. T-SQL used in Microsoft SQL Server does not have anything like `set transaction read only`

Comment: @Raj, Can you suggest a gook book for beginner like me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mentioning some information regarding a programming languages in relation with sql server like c# instead of dealing with sql-server itself.As far as I know, setting transaction as read-only and isolation levels are concerned to [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) matters